# Is it possible to make a synchronous Visualforce remoting call?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, remote-access

I have a VF page where i need to make synchronous call.Is there any possibility for making Visualforce remoting  call synchronous.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't think you can make it synchronous, but you could probably do something like disable the page while the call is occurring.

Comment: This is one of those questions where you're asking how you can use a hammer to cut a plank of wood, instead of asking what tool you should use to cut a plank of wood. You should ask a new question focused on the original problem, not on how to use a tool incorrectly. You'll get much better (and useful) answers this way.

Comment: Why not use `actionFunction` definitions instead? These allow you to use `controller`/`extension` functionality (albeit `stateful` instead of `static`). The key is that they do in fact run `synchronously` (at least I believe they do).

Answer (score 8):

No. The framework requires a callback function, and it will always run asynchronously. Besides, it's now deprecated in most browsers (you'll get warnings in the console), so you shouldn't try to make any callouts synchronous, as this model may very well be disabled entirely in the future. The reason why it's asynchronous is because JavaScript isn't multithreaded, so a synchronous read freezes the entire browser until it's done.